# How to run gdal_rasterize with sql option?

Tags: python, gdal, sql, rasterization

I'm running `gdal_rasterize` via a python pipe. When using the `-l` option, the raster is created just fine but I can't manage to get `-sql` option to work. Well my raster will be created but consists only of NAN's. What am I missing?

```
    rasterize_args = ['gdal_rasterize',
                      '-a', attribute_name,
                      '-sql', "select {attribute} FROM {layer}".format(attribute=attribute_name, layer=layer_name),
                      #'-l', layer_name,
                      '-a_nodata', str(no_data_value),
                      '-co', "COMPRESS=DEFLATE",
                      '-a_srs', srs.ExportToWkt(),
                      '-te', str(minx), str(miny), str(maxx), str(maxy),
                      '-ts', str(ds.RasterXSize), str(ds.RasterYSize),
                      ]
    if where_clause:
        rasterize_args.extend(['-where', where_clause])

    rasterize_args.extend([input_source, destination_raster])
    logger.debug("The gdal_rasterize cmd args are: %s", rasterize_args)
    ps = subprocess.Popen(
        args=rasterize_args,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE
    )
    output = ps.communicate()[0]
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to select a geometry to rasterize, and not just an attribute. For example:

```
SELECT gid, geom, attr FROM my_table WHERE name='Newbridge';
```

Furthermore, I'm not sure if you can mix `-sql` with `-where`. It's not documented how they would interact, but I'd do some testing with this.

Also, I would run this directly through Python with `gdal.RasterizeLayer` (see [API docs](http://gdal.org/gdal__alg_8h.html#adfe5e5d287d6c184aab03acbfa567cb1)) rather than through a subprocess. You would need to create or open a writable GDAL dataset and an OSR datasource which you can throw `ExecuteSQL(sql)` at to get a rasterizable layer. It might take a while to figure out how to make it work in Python, but I've found it worthwhile.